# Github App permission required to upload an asset to a release

Tags: github-api, github-app, github-release

What is the permission required to upload an asset to a release via a github app? (no OAuth)

I need to POST to url like `https://{{git_url}}/api/uploads/repos/{{owner}}/{{repo}}/releases/{{releaseNumber}}/assets?name={{assetName}}`

In the permission page there is no POST to `/repos/:owner/:repo/releases/:release_id/assets`

Im on GitHub Enterprise 2.22.17.

---

Currently I am getting

```
502 Bad Gateway {
  message: 'Error uploading to https://media.{{git_url}}/releases/{{releaseNumber}}/files: 404',
  request_id: '******'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unclear to me as well. I do get this error from a GitHub Actions step trying to deploy something to GitHub Releases, until I created a custom Personal Access Token that has full repo permissions, and nothing else selected:

[image]

I haven't yet tried deselecting any of those to get the smallest set required.

GitHub Enterprise 3.0.13 here.

Comment: Thank you, yeah I assumed, it would only be possible with OAuth scopes. Documentations are definitely not clear. I asked the question here as well: https://github.community/t/github-app-permission-required-to-release-an-asset/192879